# Add a language to spellcheck in Lync

Tags: windows-7, language, spell-check, lync, lync-2013

I'm working with `Lync` and I quite often write message in French & English. My messages are spell-checked well in French but I can't do the same for English.

Is there a way to add a language for the Lync Spell Checker so it can check both language (even if I have to set it each time I type this is not an issue for me)?

Btw I use Lync 2013 32bits on a W7 Entreprise in English.

Answer (score 2):

Lync actually uses the current input language for the spell checking.

You can thus choose the language as follows:

1. Add all input languages that you want to use in Windows' Input Language settings (combined with your usual keyboard layout)
2. Open Lync
3. Change input language in the Task Bar

The only problem is that the input language is per-application so it applies to all conversions, even if you disable the tabbed mode. I guess there is nothing we can do against that.

Found via https://wlmail.wordpress.com/spelling0/